# You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders

Tags: laravel, git, vue.js, atom-editor, laravel-mix

Im trying to compile some css and this happens.

The following appears in my console while using laravel mixer:

```
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.

    |
    |
    > .contacts-list{
    |   flex: 2;
    |   max-height: 600px;
```

This is my css in my editor:

```
<style lang="sccs" scoped>
      .contacts-list{
        flex: 2;
        max-height: 600px;
        overflow: scroll;
        border-left: 1px solid #a6a6a6;
      }
      ul{
        list-style-type: none;
        padding-left: 0;
      }
    </style>
```

Comment: You have a typo: `sccs`